A proposition about divisors (Riemann-Roch Theorem)
I am studying the book "Algebraic curves: An introduction to algebraic geometry", by Fulton, and I want to show that $C\neq \mathbb{P}^1(k)$ implies that there exists a non-principal divisor such that $deg(D)=0$, where $C$ is a non-singular and irreducible projective curve. I'm stuck on the last part, but I'll write what I understood with help of friends until I get to it.
Let $\varphi\in K(C).$ Then we have the morfism $$(\varphi:1)=f:C\to\mathbb{P}^1(k),$$ which induces a $k$-homomorphism of fields $$f^\ast :k(t)\hookrightarrow K(C)$$ where $t\mapsto \varphi$. I want to show that $$[K(C):k(\varphi)]=deg((\varphi)_0)=deg((\varphi)_\infty).$$
Suppose $char(k)=0.$ By the primitive element theorem, $$K(C)=k(\varphi,\psi),$$ where $\psi$ is algebraic over $k(\varphi).$ We have then a birational morphism $$(\varphi:\psi:1)=g:C\to C'\subset\mathbb{P}^2(k),$$ where $C'=Z(F)$ and $F(\varphi,\psi,1)=0$.
In $C'$, $\varphi = x/z.$ If $(0:1:0)\notin C'$, then $$deg((\varphi)_0)=\sum_{P\in x\cap F} (F,x)_P =deg(F)=[K(C):k(\varphi)].$$
But if $(0:1:0)\in C'$, what happens? I know that the same conclusion holds, but why? How can I get that?
Then I will be able to conclude that $D=P-Q$ is a principal divisor if and only if $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1(k)$.
